# How do I properly focus on a scrolling div that is on top of another scrolling div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a modal view that has content longer than its boundaries so I set the `overflow-y: scroll`. However the issue is that the modal view sits on top of the body which also has scrolling enabled, so when I attempt to focus on the modal view and scroll, it will sometimes grab the body and scroll that rather than the modal. It seems to disregard z-index values.

Is there any jQuery I can use to just focus on the modal view when present and totally disregard anything below it?

here is the html & css for the modal div:

```
<div class="modal-window">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-image"></div>
        <ul class="modal-details">
          <li>Placeholder text</li>
          <li>Placeholder text</li>
          <li>Placeholder text</li>
          <li>Placeholder text</li>
          <li>Placeholder text</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

.modal-window {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 100px;
  width: 476px;
  height: 618px;
  border: 1px solid white;

}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and here is a video demonstrating the issue :

https://s3.amazonaws.com/whatever12345/hggg.mov

as you can see rather than just focusing on the modal, it grabs the body underneath and scrolls that as well, some points even disregarding the modal and interacting with the body, how do I just focus on the modal when its present and totally disregard any element underneath?

Comment: need a `demo` and also your codes here!

Comment: please share your HTML and jquery code here...we give you only suggestions not functionality

Comment: check updated question @jiff

Comment: check updated question @DhavalPatel

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to have only one scroll at a time.

There are couple of ways to do it.

- You can disable the body scroll when modal is open, by adding overflow:hidden; and have scroll only for the modal container.
- another way is to remove main body content out of the body context by making it positing:fixed and let the modal use body scroll (this method help to avoid page shake which happens in first case by adding and removing scroll)

Comment: would it be possible to put your solutions into code?

Comment: I would need more code of yours to check how you trigger modal etc.